# Load Imageview from server path

Tags: android, image, server, imageview, connection

I have many images stored in a server. I want to display one of those image in a imageview.
Server and phone are under the same network and i take the path of the image from a database.
I tried with Picasso and BitmapFactory using http://path or file://path.
Someone have any tips?

Comment: It is your server. You are the one responsible for knowing what the URL is to reference an image on the server. We cannot tell you what the URL is. Hopefully it starts with `https`, but after that, it is based on how you set up the server and the content that it serves. We can tell you that using an image-loading library like Picasso (or Glide) is a great idea.

Comment: thanks @CommonsWare for the answer but i think that when i try to use Picasso to take the image from the server it show nothing because i need the credential. Do you know how can i put username and password?

Comment: Well, that depends entirely on what authentication mechanism is used by your server. For example, if it is HTTP Basic Authentication, you can put the username and password in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Glide library to do it!
Add to your `app/build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
}
```

Use this code where you want to call it,

```
GlideApp.with(context)
    .load("http://theImageFromYourHost.com/404.png")
    .into(yourImageView);
```